# SQL Transactional Replication Limits

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, administrator

I am seeing strange behavior in a Transactional Replication configuration.

Details:
Publication Server SQL 2017 Standard
Distribution Server SQL 2017 Standard
Subscriber Server SQL 2017 Standard

55 databases on the publisher with two articles(tables) per database

I have everything working in this configuration.

As soon as I try to build the same publisher/subscriber setup on another SQL 2017 Standard server pointing to the same SQL Distributor then I start seeing distribution and log reader agent jobs on the distributor show between retries and snapshots will not even run from the GUI or SQL Agent.

Some of the errors point to worker threads, so I increased TSQL, LogReader, Distributor and Snapshot threads to a large number beyond their defaults.

After restarting SQL Server agent that does not fix anything.

I am at a loss and not sure what I am missing. I have worked with replication in the past with more publishers, articles and subscribers flowing through a single distribution server and not seen this behavior.

Does anyone have any suggestions on paths I can try as I need to add a lot more publications.

Comment: What errors exactly do you get? Is there anything in Error Log(SQL Server and SQL Agent)?

Comment: So to be clear, you have 55 Publishers on one server and another 55 Publishers on another server, for a total of 110 Publishers being funneled through the same Distributor?

Comment: That is my plan.

Comment: The replication agent encountered a failure. See the previous job step history message or Replication Monitor for more information. The step failed.

Comment: Since I deleted the publications, I lost the job history with the error message.  One thing that I did work out was I could run the snapshot from the command line as I found via Google.  So that again points me to the SQL Agent limitaion.

Comment: @GarryBargsley Heads up, unless you tag someone with `@TheirUsername` (like I just did here to you) they won't know you replied to them. I just stumbled back in here out of curiosity.